# Queue FIFO search speed up through the change of visited array?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, queues

As I was preparing for the [CCC](https://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2020/index.html) this year, I am quite confused as to why a certain code modification was able to speed up my code for CCC Seniors Problem 2.

Here was the C++ source code for my first attempt, which scored **13/15** in the cccgrader website as well as the [DMOJ](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc20s2) online judging website.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> vint;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
vector<pii> vpairs[1000001];
vector<vector<bool>> vis;
int main(void){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    int A,B;
    cin>>A>>B;
    for(int i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        vector<bool> newvecbool;
        for(int j=0;j<B;j++)
        {
            newvecbool.push_back(false);
            int k;
            cin>>k;
            vpairs[k].push_back(pii(i,j));
        }
        vis.push_back(newvecbool);
    }
    queue<pii> queue;
    queue.push(pii(A,B));
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        pii curpair = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        if(curpair.first==1 && curpair.second==1){
            cout<<"yes";
            return 0;
        }
        vis[curpair.first-1][curpair.second-1] = true;
        int value = curpair.first*curpair.second;
       // cout<<curpair.first<<' '<<curpair.second<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<vpairs[value].size();i++)
        {
            pii pair = vpairs[value][i];
            if(!vis[pair.first][pair.second]){
                //vis[pair.first][pair.second] = true;
                queue.push(pii(pair.first+1,pair.second+1));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"no";
}
```

Here, on the other hand, was my second attempt, being much faster in time and scoring **15/15** on both the cccgrader and the DMOJ judging website.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int> vint;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
vector<pii> vpairs[1000001];
vector<vector<bool>> vis;
int main(void){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    int A,B;
    cin>>A>>B;
    for(int i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        vector<bool> newvecbool;
        for(int j=0;j<B;j++)
        {
            newvecbool.push_back(false);
            int k;
            cin>>k;
            vpairs[k].push_back(pii(i,j));
        }
        vis.push_back(newvecbool);
    }
    queue<pii> queue;
    queue.push(pii(A,B));
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        pii curpair = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        if(curpair.first==1 && curpair.second==1){
            cout<<"yes";
            return 0;
        }
        //vis[curpair.first-1][curpair.second-1] = true;
        int value = curpair.first*curpair.second;
       // cout<<curpair.first<<' '<<curpair.second<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<vpairs[value].size();i++)
        {
            pii pair = vpairs[value][i];
            if(!vis[pair.first][pair.second]){
                vis[pair.first][pair.second] = true;
                queue.push(pii(pair.first+1,pair.second+1));
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"no";
}
```

As you may have noticed, the only difference between the two source codes is the position in which the **vis** vector, a vector used to store the pairs of integers of visited coordinates,  is set to **true**. after visit of a coordinate point. One is right after the if statement, whilst one is in the while loop. I'm not quite sure what led to the speed increase.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be warned, [the next problem, especially on dmoj](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc20s3) is somewhat hideous.

Comment: @JohnL. I am trying to do that problem right now. I have tried to optimise my past array using sets so that the "string in array" is time complexity **O(n)**. However, now it is giving me memory error. Do I have to hash the strings to bypass both errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose 3 rooms each of which contains number 6 have been visited before any room the product of whose coordinates is 6 has been visited.

In the first version of your code, every room of the second kind will be put into the queue 3 times.

In the second version of your code, every room of the second kind will be put into the queue only 1 time (except possibly the room at (A,B), which will be put into the queue 2 times).

The difference between 3 times and 1 time is what slows down the first version. In general, there might be $m$ rooms of the first kind for the corresponding second kind. The appropriate average of $m$ in the test cases is substantially greater than 1. Hence you see the significant speedup from the first version to second version.

---

A good rule of thumb across all these kinds of searching problems is to try setting `visited` as soon as possible to avoid unnecessary and sometimes even incorrect computations.

Comment: Another speedup is to use an unordered set to record the products that have been visited. Unless that set does not contain `value`, the algorithm will skip the innermost `for` loop on `vpairs[value]`.